# no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError) when running a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

When I try to run a migration i get the following error:

migration:

```
 rails g migration ChangeFieldToText
```

error:

```
    6: from -e:1:in `<main>'
5: from /Users/rook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
4: from /Users/rook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
3: from /Users/rook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
2: from /Users/rook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
1: from /Users/rook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/Users/rook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

I've already tried resetting the database and dropping the table. This call was working before so I'm stumped why it's not working now

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone running into this, I ended up rebooting my computer and fixed the issue

Comment: This doesn't seem like the "solution". It may have included the solution, but rebooting itself wouldn't fix type errors. My guess is you might be running a different ruby version now than when that error appeared, or a different gem version. Maybe you just needed to reboot the server or get a new terminal window? Or restart your database?